# Mysql subtract from another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have tried to search this forum for an answer but can't seem to find one.

My problem: I have 3 tables. One with items, one with in-going deliveries and one with outgoing deliveries.

Table called items:

```
id | item_name 
----------------
1  | Bike
2  | Helmet
3  | Pedal
4  | Light
```

Table called ingoing:

```
id | item_id | quantity
-----------------------
1  | 2       | 5
2  | 3       | 2
3  | 4       | 1
4  | 1       | 5
5  | 2       | 4
6  | 1       | 6
7  | 3       | 5
```

Table called outgoing:

```
id | item_id | quantity
-----------------------
1  | 3       | 2
2  | 1       | 1
3  | 2       | 3
4  | 3       | 4
5  | 1       | 2
6  | 2       | 1
7  | 4       | 1
```

What I want to do is get the total amount in stock by subtracting the outgoing deliveries from the in-going and order it by the item with the least amount.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

This is the query that I got, but the SUM amounts isn't correct. Can someone help me and explain why the SUM amounts isn't correct and how should I solve this with the best way?

```
SELECT items.id AS ID, 
       items.item_name, 
       Sum(ingoing.quantity) - Sum(outgoing.quantity) AS InStock
FROM   items
       LEFT JOIN ingoing 
              ON ingoing.item_id = items.id
       LEFT JOIN outgoing 
              ON outgoing.item_id = items.id
 GROUP BY ID
 ORDER BY InStock ASC
```

This is the result I want from this:

```
ID | item_name | InStock
---------------------------
4  | Light     | 0
3  | Pedal     | 1
2  | Helmet    | 5
1  | Bike      | 8
```

What I Get:

```
ID | item_name | InStock
---------------------------
4  | Light     | 0
3  | Pedal     | 2
2  | Helmet    | 10
1  | Bike      | 16
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Please provide your test data which are existed in current tables.

Comment: Please can you provide what kind of data are you getting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easy to forget the multiplicative effect of a join.  When you encounter problems like this, check the result of the join, prior to filtering/grouping:

```
SELECT items.id, 
       items.item_name,
       ingoing.id  AS ingoing,
       outgoing.id AS outgoing
FROM   items
       LEFT JOIN ingoing 
              ON ingoing.item_id = items.id
       LEFT JOIN outgoing 
              ON outgoing.item_id = items.id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ddc5/1/0).

As you can see, the resultset contains multiple records with the same `ingoing.id` values, and multiple records with the same `outgoing.id` values.  This is because each ingoing record for a particular item has joined with every outgoing record for that same item: thus there are 4 pedals in the resultset (2 incoming x 2 outgoing), etc.

Aggregating each table by item prior to joining (and thus ensuring that there is only 1 record per item on each side of the join) will achieve what you're after:

```
SELECT items.id AS ID, 
       items.item_name, 
       ingoing.quantity - outgoing.quantity AS InStock
FROM   items
       LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT   item_id AS id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
         FROM     ingoing
         GROUP BY item_id
       ) AS ingoing USING (id)
       LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT   item_id AS id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
         FROM     outgoing
         GROUP BY item_id
       ) AS outgoing USING (id)
ORDER BY InStock ASC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ddc5/2/0).

Note that your problem would have been greatly simplified by only having a single underlying table of stock movements, with positive quantities indicating movements in one direction and negative quantities indicating movements in the opposite direction: then a simple groupwise summation of the whole table would yield your desired results.

Comment: Very good explanation! This seems to solve my problem, thank you! Tho I see another problem now, I don't know how to use JOIN properly here because if I add another item and it has just an ingoing quantity and no ourgoing, it doesn't show the quantity, just NULL. Do you know how to fix this? Here You got fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ead2/1)

Comment: @cybrz: You can use `IFNULL(outgoing.quantity, 0)` in the select list/subtraction.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal But the problem is that the item can have a value (coming from ingoing quantity) and if theres no outgoing quantity is shows NULL. I understand what you mean but I don't think it works in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT items.id AS ID, items.item_name, (SELECT SUM(quantity) from ingoing 
WHERE ingoing.item_id = items.id) - (SELECT SUM(quantity) from outgoing WHERE
outgoing.item_id = items.id) AS InStock FROM  items ORDER BY InStock ASC;
```